# Calling different python functions with different key press in python

Tags: python

I have two functions: `screenshot()` and `reader()`. I want `screenshot()` to be called when `0` is pressed, and `reader()` to be called when `1` is pressed. And it should exit, if `d` is pressed. This is how I tried:

```
from PIL import Image
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import datetime
import time
import os
import pyperclip

def screenshot():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        im=ImageGrab.grab()
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        file_name = "sample_" + timestr + ".png"
        file_location = os.path.join('/path', file_name)
        im.save(file_location)

def reader():
    pyperclip.copy("sample")

while True:
    x = raw_input('Press enter for a random letter...')
    print x
    if x == "0":
        screenshot()

    if x == "1":
        reader()

    if x == "d":
        break
```

But it is not working as expected. When I press `0`, nothing happens. When I press `1`, nothing happens. But when `d` is pressed for the first time, it calls `screenshot()`. And next time `d` is pressed, it exits.

Comment: I would change 2 of those if statements into elif statements (and raise an error if else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line `if __name__ == "__main__":`.
And reader() is working, do you know how it works? its copying a `sample` text, try to paste in your text editor.